# gcc C++ Linker make "type of 'X' does not match original declaration" an error?

Tags: c++, gcc, linker, g++

How do I make the following linker warning about a wrong extern declaration an error? I am compiling & linking with gcc version 4.8.3 Sourcery CodeBench

uilding target: xxxxx.elf
Invoking: Cross ARM C++ Linker
arm-none-eabi-g++ -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -O0 -fmessage-length=0 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -flto  -g3 -T "..\config\stm32f4ems\STM32F407xG_CCM.ld" -Xlinker --gc-sections -Wl,-Map,"rusefi.map" -Wl,-Map,"rusefi.map" -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -g3 ....

**xxx.cpp:584:21: warning: type of 'afrMap' does not match original declaration [enabled by default]**

extern fuel_Map3D_t afrMap;

I would like this to not succeed so that I do not miss the issue again.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the flag `-Werror`

From [this link](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html):

```
-Werror
Make all warnings into errors.
```

EDIT:
If you want to be more specific, you can use

```
-Werror=
Make the specified warning into an error.
```

Comment: This would work for a compiler but does not seem to work for the linker   Building target: rusefi.elf
Invoking: Cross ARM C++ Linker
arm-none-eabi-g++ -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -O0 -fmessage-length=0 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -flto  -g3 -T "..\config\stm32f4ems\STM32F407xG_CCM.ld" -Xlinker --gc-sections -Wl,-Map,"rusefi.map" -Wl,-Map,"rusefi.map" -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -g3 -Werror -o "rusefi.elf"   ./util/crc.o  ...
arm-none-eabi-g++.exe: error: ./ru: No such file or directory
cs-make: *** [rusefi.elf] Error 1